# How do I make ballerina fishnets?

Tags: modeling

Okay everyone,do you remember Ballora from Five Nights at Freddy's: Sister Location.

Well,I'm making a model of her and I was wondering if you can give me a hint on how to model the fishnets she wears on her legs.

[image]

I'm kind of having trouble with modeling them.

[image]

I've tried decimating the faces of the secondary calf mesh and it didn't work like I hoped it would.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: For the base topology (ribbon like) you can use snap to face option and shrinkwrap modifier to the legs. Then a solidify modifier.

Comment: This may help somewhat http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve/58963#58963