# Request - Cable Cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

I need to achieve this result

a cloth simulation of elastic sheath for tubes, cables, wire like this:

[image]

there is a sample video for c4d and other software

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXi57AAWu4M

https://lesterbanks.com/2017/07/modeling-cloth-cover-cables-c4d/

thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to model braided nylon sleeve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve)

Comment: I want model it with cloth simulation for realistic result over the overall shape based on the inside tubes or cables

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: The fabric is not elastic and falls like a curtain around the cables, I do not get the enveloping effect of the sheath on the cable as in the sample photos

Comment: Welcome to bse @Enrico.  Suggest editing more info into question to clarify. esp. what you have tried so far.  In particular cloth settings like pinning.