# Easy way to model spiral engraving (knurling) that is usually used on metal for better grip?

Tags: modeling

What is the easiest way to model this diamond grip pattern into a cylinder?

[image: Spiral-like engraving for better grip.]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve

Comment: In case it helps, the pattern is usually called knurling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knurling

Answer (score 23):

1. Subdivide the area you want to engrave to have enough supporting geometry:

   [image]
2. Subdivide it one more time - <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide:

   [image]
3. Unsubdivide - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > Unsubdivide, choose *Iterations*: 1 in operator properties:

   [image]
4. Select single face and select similar - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > Area:

   [image]
5. Poke faces <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and switch to vert select:

   [image]
6. Select these 2 vertices:

   [image]
7. Select similar - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > Amount of connecting edges:

   [image]
8. Scale these in with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>:

   [image]
9. Mark sharp smoothing on the whole area.

Answer (score 13):

You could achieve this with normal mapping in Blender. Use a normal map like for an example this:
[Normal map](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9e/45/96/9e45966313bdbc160ac3f3fffa7fc187.jpg)

You can then in cycles create a material which uses the normal map to simulate the light bouncing of in certain ways to achieve this effect. You will have to UV unwrap the model, and assign the material with the normal map on the places you want it.[image: This is the texture assigned to a standard cylinder][image]