# How do you add orderly wrinkles to faces?

Tags: faces

[image]

I want to add some wrinkles on the side faces of the lid like the left image

I'm a beginner so detailed explanation would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thats a similar problem to [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/116466/935), the suggestions there should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Checker Deselect]

- If you want your lid to stay flat, so you can put a nice bevel on it, extrude the cylinder's cap-poly first. This will create a circular loop to hold that edge.
- Get **enough separations** in the side of the cylinder to hold your
  detail.
- **Select the parts you want to push in**, the "valleys". 
  If you have a lot of those, after selecting the whole row of edges, use **Mesh > Checker Deselect** to get the pattern of selection, that you want
- **Shrink/Fatten** the faces in or out (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)or **Extrude** them into or out of the cylinder (<kbd>E</kbd>) by using **Individual Origin** as the Pivot Point.