# Select Cylinder into Equal Sections?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, selection-tools

I'm making a mesh that requires about 6 extrusions from the base model. And Each extrusion needs to be equally spaced apart around the cylinder. Before, I would have to count over and over again the amount of faces in between each selected face "clumps" and it just became really tedious. Is there a way to select (for example) 7 out of every (another example) 33 faces equally spaced apart around a cylinder?

[image]

Comment: If the mesh already has those faces cut in then Checker Deselect with propoer setup of Skip and Nth selection will select you according to any pattern. It won't make anything evenly spaced obviously, it will only select existing geometry.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116534/how-do-you-add-orderly-wrinkles-to-faces/132203#132203

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You could select all the outside faces, and from the header 'Select'
  menu, use 'Checker Deselect', which, starting from your active face,
  will skip the deselection of the number of faces set in 'Skip' and
  leave a gap of N-1 faces entered in the 'Nth Selection' field, before
  skipping again. Sometimes, though, that's surprisingly counterintuitive.
- If you've got a lot of rotationally symmetrical work to do, it's worth considering cutting a segment out of your cylinder, and recreating the whole with an Array modifier, set to 'Object Offset', with a rotated Empty at the center of the cylinder as the modifier's target. Then, by working on one segment, you're working on them all.

But for one-off operations like this, it's often quicker to make a jig: a temporary helper object you can delete later.

In the illustration, I've <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicated a chunk of faces, <kbd>E</kbd> extruded it <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, scaled it down in Z, and again, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicated it, this time immediately following up with <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>60</kbd> rotating the thickened chunk by 60 degrees. Now hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> repeatedly will send copies round the cylinder. In this case, they're just markers to save you counting, but they could be snap targets, or view targets.

[image]

It may seem a silly amount of work, but once your favorite shortcuts are under your belt, this kind of operation for stashing lengths an angles can become very straightforward, and speed modelling up a lot.

Comment: Thanks Man! This is exactly what I was looking for!