# Braided hose modeling

Tags: modeling

HoW could I make braided hose like this, I know I have to use array but I have troubles making piece that should be arrayed.

[image]

Here is higher res but I don't need those single threads to be show but just single like in image above.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I saw this But couldn't use it for my model

Comment: i read this title as "braindead horse modelling" and was somewhat disappointed when i clicked on it

Comment: It seems so flat that you could probably get same results with a simple tube + bump map texture. But that is probably not a modeling answer.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282515/how-to-make-braided-tubing

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200650/braided-cord-with-curve-and-bevel-curve) a more accurate answer.

And here is a simpler solution for the first picture (but you can use this kind of solution to fake the second one):

- Create 2 bricks (front view), the proportion is 2 x 1 units, subdivide a bit, rotate them 45° and stick them together.

[image]

- Use a first *Array* modifier to duplicate them on the X axis. Find the good *Relative Offset* value.

[image]

- Use a second *Array* modifier to duplicate them on the Z axis. Again, find the good *Relative Offset* value.

[image]

- Add a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode, find the good *Deform Angle* value (more than 360°).

[image]

- Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and press *Smooth Shading*.
- To make it follow a curve, use a *Curve* modifier.

[image]