# how do I wrap a net around geometry

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

Imagine you have a net woven of thin ropes. I want to wrap it around an object as in the picture below:

[image]

So far I have tried something that does not work the way I like:

1. create a net using a 6-gon using three array modifiers
2. use simple deform --> bend to create kind of cylinder
3. shrink-wrap the resulting net-cylinder around an object

here's what I get after step 3:

[image]

Then I convert to geometry (all modifiers get applied), then I convert back to splines, then I use a circle as bevel shape to arrive at this:

[image]

The resulting net is too 'bendy', and it's also smooth instead of being ropes. So.. I want those ropes wrapped around an object. Any ideas how to achive this?

My another idea was to wrap a plane around and use an alpha of a net with a displacement modifier but I have not tried it yet. It also would take a lot of effort to get a proper alpha, so maybe you have better ideas at this point.

Thank you!

Comment: why not array a pattern then bend the whole thing with the Simple Deform modifier?

Comment: @moonboots but it also has to shrinkwrap onto an object. and if I use shrinkwrap those pattern whould be broken because it would all stick to the surface of the model. If I understood you correctly

Comment: you don't have to shrinkwrap it, once you've applied the Simple Deform (Bend mode) to make it a 360° cylinder, you can deform it a bit if you want, either with Proportional Editing or with a Mesh Deform

Comment: @moonboots yes, that would be one option for sure, thanks. I imagine that proportional editing would be a lot of tweaking to match the shape in the first place, and shrinkwrap seemed like a must to me. because then you can for example stretch the net, but it would still perfectly stick to the surface. I don't really like the idea to bend and manually fit it to the surface.

Comment: but why do you need to make your pattern stick to the surface? Make the surface part of a flat pattern, then bend the whole thing 360°, and you have your result

Comment: like here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131443/braided-hose-modeling/131449#131449

Comment: @moonboots I see what you mean... surely I will give a go.. but I don't think it would do though because my shape is not really a 360 cylinder. That grip of a sword if you take a close look it's much flatter that a cylinder, and it also has uneven surface. this is the first.. and the second is that afterwards I want to tweak the net manually, and it still has to stick to the grip surface tightly if you know what I mean. I don't say this wouldnl't work - just give me some time to wrap my head around how I can fit your proposed solution to my case

Comment: yes but i must not be clear enough, the handle must also be part of the object that you'll bend afterwards, it's the same object as the net, so the net will always stick. Also once you have bent you can flatten or deform as you want with Mesh Deform or Proportional Editing...

Comment: sure, I understood, this is exactly how it is in the page you referenced. I make kind of a uv-unwrap of the handle and do all the surface beforehand (a plane), then a bend and I get the grip. Then I can flatten it a bit. The problem is if I want to slide the net along or stretch it or otherwise tweak it, it would be breaking the grip as well. or? because when I touch the net, I thouch the grip (it's one surface) and that would be it.

Comment: so, if I manage to get the net exactly I want it to look b e f o r e bending, so that I don't have to tweak at all, this would work

Comment: and what if I do it the way you proposed but I achieve the net with a displacement, and, after bending I tweak it by tweaking the UVs? and this would shift the net along the grip, even after bending. what do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you say when you're talking about the risk that it breaks the grip, if you give enough geometry to the grip it will be deformed with the net, you can even extrude the net from the plane at the beginning so that it's only one mesh, and it you don't want the net to stick to the grip, once the Simple Deform applied, hide the grip, move the net, etc...

Comment: Ok, let me just try it instead of arguing further. So, I'll start with a plane, extrude the net from this plane, bend to get a grip, do mesh deform etc. and then I'll try to make adjustments to the net the way you described. so, I'll try those couple of things and get back... thank you for taking time!