# Braided cord with curve and bevel curve

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I have here a set of two curves with a bevel object that I have made to have limited clipping issues, but the problem comes about when I want to array the two curves, If I try to array them the bevel object does not carry through effectively to the new arrayed curves, and if I convert to mesh and turn the mesh into a curve to bevel the twist of the sections does not carry over either. Anyone know a fix to this problem?

Comment: Would a shader solution be acceptable, or do you need the geometry?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131443/braided-hose-modeling https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve

Answer (score 6):

Edit 2023. Create 2 perpendicular meshes:

[image]

Array along X:

[image]

Array along Z:

[image]

Bend on Z it with a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode):

[image]

Give it thickness etc:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response, but as the answer you linked goes, it is faking the detail of braiding, not actually braiding it.

Comment: OK I've edited to make it more accurate  ;)