# How to make braided tubing?

Tags: modeling

I am looking on how to produce braided tubing in blender. Below is what I'm trying to replicate. Any help would be much appreciated[image]

Comment: I would have 3 cylinders, each with a different material.   Braiding would use some Brick-like texture to include it's alpha Principle BDSF node for the "see through" effect; inner some glass-like material node.  I might use a Shrinkwrap modifier on the 2 outer cylinders to "fit" those over the inner cylinder as I bend or otherwise position the inner one.

Comment: Let's quickly change the title before anyone sees it :D - [tutorial requests are considered off topic on BSE](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131443/braided-hose-modeling https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200650/braided-cord-with-curve-and-bevel-curve

Answer (score 9):

### version – Modifiers

Add a mesh *Circle* 12 points, *Delete* > *Only Face&Edges*.
Modifiers in this order:

- Screw (spiral)
- Screw (strip wide)
- Mirror (strip crossing)
- Solidify (thickness)

[image]

Two other *Cylinders* for inner and outer tube with correspond material.

[image]

To add a bit of randomness to braid I added *Geometry Nodes* modifier after the first *Screw* to random a bit wire crossing ... *Random Value* for *Offset* socket of *Set Position* node.

[image]

To make it more realistic you can duplicate wires before Mirror modifier Mirror it and Solidify in negative direction. Or for more precise modelling -Apply the first Screw modifier and manually select every second point and Scale on X,Y a bit  ... so you get up&down crossing.

### version – Geometry Nodes

[image]

Spiral stroke segment generates already first node, all the others are to set strip, correct Tilt and Extrude, shade Smooth limited by Split Edge node (factor Edge Angle) ...
[image]

... segment arrayed and mirrored (by Scale -1).
[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit: Knitching**
All the techniques here use braid in one direction above a crossing direction, but in reality it is up&down knitching ... so here is some way ...

[image]

[image]

Node-tree is longer, so instead of sharing screen check the file ...

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Generate stripes using e.g. wave textures (or just math: ping-pong on coordinates). You might need to rotate your UV map inside the shader if it's generated procedurally (I'm using a bevel on a curve here). Then just compose one over the other - I'm not using a Mix node because the color is same for both layers, also I'm not making the stripes intertwined, which would require slightly more logic. Modifying normals for more 3D effect:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The other provided answers are great.

[image]

Here's one more way:

1.Add subdivisions so that you have a lot of squares

[image]

2. In face edit mode, select all, right-click and 'poke faces'

[image]

3. Select one vertical edge, Shift+G, length, then Ctrl+X to dissolve the selection

[image]

4. Ctrl+Alt+click an edge to select an edge ring, press F3 and type 'loop' and select 'select loops: edge loops'

[image]

5. Press 'P' to separate. Hide the other object for clarity. Select the new object and right-click and select 'convert to curve' (note, NOT the other curveS option)

[image]

6. Make a plane object, in face edit mode, select all, press X: remove ONLY faces, convert that to curve in object mode
7. make that as the Bevel Object of the spiral curve object

[image]

8. Make the Twist method tangent:

[image]

9. Check 'Fill Caps'

[image]

10. Add some subdivisions for the 'Plane' Bevel object. Make the spiral object smooth by right-clicking and select 'Shade Smooth'.

Ask in comments if some thing's are hard to do, I can elaborate by editing this answer.

[image]

Comment: I went by this way too :) Than I changed my mind ... BTW to create such curve you can use addon Extra Curves (packed with blender) > Spirals ... so you can skip first five steps.

Comment: @vklidu I'm glad you changed your mind :) Your new answer is very clever! Creating the answer was more effort than I thought, also - could've been a shame to have to duplicate answers

Comment: Yeap :) I know that feeling ... it happened to me several times, after a few hours of creating answer to notice its already answered is frustrating ... I already tried to propose some "reservation" system (or some notification someone is working on answer) would be helpful. Luckily this wasn't the case :) Very nice result.

Comment: i am personally totally against any reservation, but...an information "somebody is writing an answer" might be helpful if you don't want to waste your time... ;) But i saw indeed somebody writing things like "but i wrote something in the comments and you answered it..." as if they could reserve it...i could only laugh! :D

Comment: @Chris IMO submitting a work-in-progress versions of a long answer would be totally okay if in the end it says "Answer writing in progress. Update soon to see the edits." or something. I think I might just do that for the next long answer of mine.