# How we design of 3D Tissue weave with the geometry nodes technique

Tags: geometry-nodes

The geometry of tissue cell differs from cell to cell as they are similar to each other in sequence and structure.
I have found in softwares that the design of the geometry depends on the shape of the node and the profile which represented as a curve of the sine (sinus), where a curve is drawn, as well as the section of the node, which is most often in the form of a circle or an oval. ..., then, we deploy the node on the curve to obtain a special section, then we generate several curves for the first node of the same direction. Then we repeat the procedure for the nodes or curves, and this time these curves are perpendicular to the first curve.
Until we get what we call **Tissue weave 3D**.
The process can be repeated horizontally to obtain a grid, as shown in the attached images.
Is it possible to help for the design of a 3D Tissue weave with the geometry nodes technique.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These weaves could certainly could be constructed, using Geometry Nodes, but before deciding that's the way to go, you could have a look at the shipped add-on _Tissue Tools_ , a large part of which is specifically built for this purpose.

Comment: The last knitting version use something you can use https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282530/2214

Comment: Do you mean Tissue addon, for these case of a flat tissue as shown in the figures I do not know how to adjus it well.

Comment: Thank you vklidu, I have already seen this page, but here it is the case of a fabric on a tube, in addition the adjustment of the section of the tissue is a difficult one.

Comment: This Addon is included in the code 3DMax: http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/weave-mesh

Answer (score 1):

Based on *Bezier Segment* ... with the first *Transform > Scale* > Z you can change waviness ...

[image]
[image]

Simple Array ...

[image]
[image]

When connected to Group Input node for simpler manipulation ...
[image]

[image]

Comment: Good vklidu?, How to make the nodes in contact?

Comment: What do you mean by nodes in contact?

Comment: Amazing, thank you vklidu, thé contact IS between tube profil. For the 3rd figure or the figure named "d", can we generate it with this technique, (See figure 1 for this paper:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10853-019-04096-1 ).

Comment: Sorry if you mean 3rd figure named "d" in your Q I don't think it would be a big question for someone who knows :) I'm stacked how to offset green strips per instance and keep start https://imgur.com/EUf61nV BTW your link needs some institution permission so I can't reach fig.1 in the link in your comment. Probably edit your Q at something simpler that covers my answer and create another one. Thanks

Comment: ... or if @RobinBetts is interested to answer :) or any geo-guru here.

Comment: The addon Nodes geometry is a powerful tool for generating structures. In the following video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBDf54D_iqI), it shows a tool that uses a special technique to generate these weaves, and especially to generate oval sections and layers between them, in this node, how to create this section?