# Braided Shield for Coax Cable Model

Tags: modeling, animation, node-editor

I can't find any blender tutorial for this kind of cable:
[image: https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/industrial/industrial-part/coaxial-cable-hd-103]

The challenge here is the braided shield:
[image]

The construction resembles the most that of a braided hose (tightly knit threads in groups of 8, even tighter than in the 3d model image at the top).
[image]

I can't use the suggested tutorials because they don't show the threads:
[image]
[image]

The closest answer I found is in this thread, but again they show how to weave strips not threads:
[How to make braided tubing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282515/how-to-make-braided-tubing?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Won't use UV Mapping because I need the threads to be visible in an animation.

It's big challenge for me as I'm a beginner, I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello maybe this will answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200650/braided-cord-with-curve-and-bevel-curve and another one that is a bit less accurate but that may help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131443/braided-hose-modeling

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/animate-winding-a-ribbon-rope-cable-around-a-cylinder/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the "Spiral Curves"

These curves are disabled by default - but you can always access them by using the inbuilt add-on "Curve: Extra Objects".

Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > [search for *'curve'*] > *enable* "Curve: Extra Objects" :

---

[image: enable extra curves]

---

After enabling it :

*(in Object Mode):*  Add > Curve > Curve Spirals > Archemedian :

[image: add curve]

**don't forget to adjust *Height* and *Radius* right after adding a curve :**
[image]

---

After adding a curve spiral – enable a round profile for it :

[image]

---

Duplicate this spiral few times — and join those spirals into a single object by pressing [Ctrl+J] — **with all spirals selected.*

Now you have a ribbon of wires which you can move, mirror, and duplicate:

[image]

**( Use duplicates of this ribbon to braid the cable )**

---

After all ribbons are placed – delete excessive vertices on the ribbons' ends (if needed).

A rough result :

[image]

Comment: Your solution looks nice but unfortunately you explained how to make a spiral but not how to achieve the actual braiding

Comment: >>"[...] how to achieve the actual braiding"____

I thought it would be kind of obvious. But since it isn't here are details:  just select one ribbon at once -> press Tab to enter 'Edit Mode'  -> Select some curve points and move them towards or away from the main cable. Do this for two or three ribbons, then just copy-paste them and arrange all that stuff to look as a braid. So, no magic here, just a little bit of a tedious work.