# making plastic mesh like texture

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to make the green mesh in the above picture

What kind of modifiers or featuers shoud I be using to make those repetition of the wires??

Comment: While it could be possibly done in array modifier with some trick, but you better look other texture creating tool (substance painter) for this job. Something like [Metal Fence](https://3dtextures.me/2019/10/01/metal-fence-001/)?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve