# What's the best method to model this atomizer with varying size and thickness?

Tags: modeling

I used the tissue modifier to make this but the mesh needs to be thicker and bigger at the end points, like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Did you look at my source image? Will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Do you mean this sort of clumping/thickening?  https://imgur.com/a/LWOlu6z My method for this is a bit scraggly atm, but could be simplified enough to be an answer..

Comment: @RobinBetts yes! much better

Comment: @RobinBetts Please share the method if possible.

Comment: @4-K coming up.... OK. But the method in my answer is flawed. Ratios are clamped by  being on a vertex-group. That needs a fix, sampling 'Nearest' in GN on an attribute instead of relying on _Tissue_ to pass the value in a vertex-group.  But this is a start, and you're in a hurry. I'll fix the answer when I can, soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hosiery on the bulb is thinner on the swollen area because it is stretched. One approach to simulating this would be start off with a base-tube, and stretch it ourselves:

[image]

This can be proportionally edited as a shape-key, or just on a duplicate.

Once made, the stretched version can be compared to the base version with a GN group, storing the ratio of lengths into a vertex-group:

[image]

(In the end, here, the attribute has to interpolated onto points, not edges, which isn't perfect. But that's why it's OK to stash onto a pre-existing vertex-group, which can be directly used by the *Tissue* tesselation)

A weight-map on the bulb results:

[image]

When you tesselate using the *Tissue* add-on, you can ask for the vertex-group to be mapped to the tesselation. This method tesselates a tileable mesh-line, without thickness:

[image]

Then uses a GN modifier on the tesselation to generate thickness, guided by the mapped vertex-group. Ideally, as a band is stretched, to preserve volume, the cross-sectional area varies as `1 / length`, and its radius varies as the square root of that:

[image]

The result is subtle, but you could fudge the square-root to another *Power* to exaggerate it.

This is the sort of result:

[image]

[image]

I'm not that fond of the workflow.. it has destructive steps. You could do both the stretching and the tessellation inside GN to improve it, but that's another question.