# Changing amount of instances scattered based on height

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am trying to scatter instances on a mesh, but I want to be able **to control the amount of instances scattered based on the height they are on the mesh.**

How would I accomplish this? *(I have a feeling it has something to do with Vectors and the Color Ramp node, but I don't know.)*

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285896/whats-the-best-method-to-model-this-atomizer-with-varying-size-and-thickness/286105#286105

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be like this one:

[image]

The important point is that Density is calculated per face. So you have to have enough polygons to do that (That's why I've added subdivide mesh)

Comment: I'll try this out later today. Thanks!

Comment: That's how I would have done it as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try to change the input to the Selection slot on the Instance on Points node based on your height value. Something like height - randomValueZeroToOne * height * modifier > threshold could work.

edit: image of setup as requested in comments
You can use the value, B input of compare node or the float curve in the threshold group to control die distribution (the float curve isn't really that necessary but gives a very nice and specific control)

[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing a screenshot of this node setup?

Comment: Sure thing, too bad I can not upload the blend file :-/
I don't really get why this post got downvoted.. except maybe that it took me two days to reply?